# how to change id pool in cognito terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cognito

I deleted a pool manually in cognito (aws) and terraform has a relation with the pool deleted so it says:

reading Amazon Cognito IDP (Identity Provider) User (xxxx): ResourceNotFoundException: User pool ********_xxxxxxxxx does not exist.

is it posible to create a new pool with a custom id in order to match the deleted one?
or there is a trick to make in terraform to avoid the error?

I tried to set a custom id in aws but i dont find the option

Comment: Its not possible to set custom id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to set a custom ID, but for fix the terraform error you can remove from the state the Cognito IDP with

```
terraform state rm ADDRESS
```

and after that or you'll recreate it with terraform or if you done by hand you can import it into the state with

```
terraform import aws_cognito_identity_provider.example us-west-2_abc123:CorpAD
```

as reported in [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_identity_provider)